# The difference between hosting's pop and Gmail's

Tags: outlook, gmail, pop3, horde

I've just tried to pop emails from my own hosting to Outlook. I found that after Outlook did a pop, emails in my hosting are gone. This is not like Gmail does for pop. I'm curious if there is a setting for this. My hosting's console is cPanel and Horde as one of its webmail.

Comment: One of a POP3 client's settings is to leave copies of messages on the server.  My guess is that the account you have configured for your host's server have that unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in the settings for your webmail, you can check "keep copy of mail after download" (or something similarly phrased) to have the server keep POP mail after it's been checked with a desktop client.